# Dynamically loading webpack bundles of another project

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

Have a `SubApp` that when built with webpack, creates a vendor.js and app.js bundles. The application built this way already works. Have a `MainApp`, that dynamically loads vendor and app bundles of `SubApp`. This doesn't work.

When loading the bundles, I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

**All code code I'm using**:

`SubApp` webpack config:

```
{
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  entry: {
    app: './app.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks(module) {
        return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

`SubApp` app.js:

```
import angular from 'angular';

angular.module('barApp', [])
 .component('foobar', {
   template: `BAR APP`,
 });
```

`MainApp` webpack config:

```
{
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  entry: {
    app: './nav.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  },
};
```

`MainApp` app.js:

```
Promise.all([
  import('./SubApp/dist/vendor.js'),
  import('./SubApp/dist/app.js'),
]).then(([ vendor, app ]) => {
  console.log('Success');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log("Chunk loading failed", err);
});
```

Running `MainApp` (whether from dev-server or built files) will produce: `Chunk loading failed TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`.

I'm using **webpack 2.5.0**.

**Edit:** Upon some investigation, it looks like I could make my current setup work, if I loaded vendor and app sequentially, doing so however would slow down loading significantly, since I'd need to wait for the big (vendor) bundle to load first before fetching the actual app.

AFAIK, modules loaded dynamically should still execute in the order they are requested, not in order of which request finishes first.

There's some pointers that I could package `SubApp` as a [library](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2589) but it's not clear to me how to do that if I want to have separate vendor and app bundles.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, but is there anything preventing you from letting MainApp bundle the SubApp's files into its distribution, effectively having the SubApp code in two distributions?

This is how I see it now, if I'm not mistaken, how users access your project.

```
MainApp, Standalone -> SubApp as a resource
SubApp, Standalone
```

While it may look like you are putting the same code in two places, I think this will cause several benefits, including being able to set some standalone environment settings for the SubApp that would be redundant or cause conflict in your Main App's environment.

As for how to actually make this work, I'd still recommend re-using webpack configs as much as possible. [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge) is a great package for this, webpack config or not, it merges beautifully and is customizable.

```
<= means 'merged from'

webpack.subapp.base.config.js
webpack.mainapp.config.js <= webpack.subapp.resource.js <= webpack.subapp.base.config
webpack.subapp.standalone.js <= webpack.subapp.base.config.js
```

So your standalone/resource configs of SubApp will load all the base values from the `base` config, while applying settings based on whether it's running standalone or not.

Also, since it looks your SubApp and MainApp are both served in the same directory (is this correct?), you will not run into directory issues when merging these configs. All the better! But if you do run into issues, just use '../' for your entries in your `resource` config for SubApp.

I hope this answer can inspire some scalability in your project! I've had these types of issues too, and usually webpack merge has been the answer. This goes for when running in dev/prod mode also, so be sure to think about those possibilities as well.

Comment: Hi William. The reason I'm using async module loading is to avoid doing what you suggested. MainApp would load in an instant since all it needs in my case it to know about modules that need to be loaded at some point on demand. In real life, there wouldn't be one but multiple SubApps. Shipping them all to MainApp would mean shipping a few MB package to the client regardless whether they'll need the functionality each SubApp has or not (and that's after minification and gzipping).

Comment: Either way, my real problem is being able to load all files at the same time, but to be able to execute them in the order they are listed - as would happen if I included <script> tags in a HTML page.